# On every call of isEmailVerified() returning the false condition, Even after email verified

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

What actually i am doing here, When a user login to their account, Then i am checking that whatever they had verified their email address or not, If not then i am starting the `EmailVerificationActivity`.
From where when user click on **SEND VERIFICATION EMAIL** Button an Email Verification code will be sent to user's email address.

[image: User is sending email verification link]

after that when user successfully verified their email address, when they click **SEND VERIFICATION LINK** Button again.

Instead of showing toast message 
`Toast.makeText(this, "Your email has been verified, Now you can login.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`,
sending the Email Verification link again.

[image: sending email verification link again]

> Why `isEmailVerified()` returning the `false` condition.

This is my **EmailVerificationActivity**

```
package com.socialcodia.sherewatan;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class EmailVerificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvEmailAddress;
    private Button btnSendVerificationEmail, btnSignOut;

    //Firebase
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;

    String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_verification);

        //Init
        tvEmailAddress = findViewById(R.id.tvEmailAddress);
        btnSendVerificationEmail = findViewById(R.id.btnSendVerificationEmail);
        btnSignOut = findViewById(R.id.btnSignOut);

        //Firebase Init
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        // get and set email address
        email = mUser.getEmail();
        tvEmailAddress.setText(email);

        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signOut();
            }
        });

        btnSendVerificationEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isEmailVerified();
            }
        });
    }

    private void isEmailVerified()
    {
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
        {
            boolean isEmailVerified = mAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified();
            if (isEmailVerified)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your email has been verified, Now you can login.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                sendVerificationEmail();
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendVerificationEmail()
    {
        mAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(EmailVerificationActivity.this, "Email verification link has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(EmailVerificationActivity.this, "Oops! Failed to send email verification link", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendToLoginWithEmail()
    {
        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("email",email);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void signOut()
    {
        mAuth.signOut();
        sendToLoginWithEmail();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How i solved the error.

```
private void isEmailVerified()
{
    mAuth.getCurrentUser().reload().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
            {
                boolean isEmailVerified = mAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified();
                if (isEmailVerified)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your email has been verified, Now you can login.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    sendVerificationEmail();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reload current user information. You see the data of the user your have from authentication are old and you need to retrieve the latest. Use the `reload()` method for that.

Comment: But i was playing with that method since yesterday. +1

Answer (score 0):

I used  the following line to solve this problem

`await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.reload();`